# Get the date of the next 15th and/or 30th day with php?

Tags: php, date

I require to get the dates of the upcoming **15th** and **30ths** of the next months as for the current date. (If February is within range it must be 28/29th of course).

Can I do this using mktime/strtotime or maybe using another method?

I got this but of course this is for only get the last day of this and next month. I need the upcoming 15ths and 30ths instead.

```
$cuota1 = date('t-m-Y', strtotime('+15 days'));
    return $cuota1;

$cuota2 = date('t-m-Y', strtotime('+30 days'));
    return $cuota2;

$cuota3 = date('t-m-Y', strtotime('+45 days'));
    return $cuota3;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope I've got your idea right, and may be this solution is quite long, but looks like it's bullet-proof:

```
$numOfDays = date('t', $todayStamp);
$base = strtotime('+'.$numOfDays.' days', strtotime(date('Y-m-01', $todayStamp)));
$day15 = date('Y-m-15', $base);
$day30 = date('Y-m-'.min(date('t', $base), 30), $base);
```

where `$todayStamp` is generally the value of `time()`, but for debug purposes it can be `strtotime()` of an arbitrary date. For example, let's take "difficult" case of the next leap year:

```
$today = '2016-01-30';
$todayStamp = strtotime($today);
$numOfDays = date('t', $todayStamp);
$base = strtotime('+'.$numOfDays.' days', strtotime(date('Y-m-01', $todayStamp)));
$day15 = date('Y-m-15', $base);
$day30 = date('Y-m-'.min(date('t', $base), 30), $base);
var_dump($day15);
var_dump($day30);
```

The output is

```
string(10) "2016-02-15"
string(10) "2016-02-29"
```

and for 2016-02-29 the output will be

```
string(10) "2016-03-15"
string(10) "2016-03-30"
```

Comment: works real great, went in the right direction on what I needed, thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a little crude but you could try something like this, though of course this doesn't validate the date at all:-

```
$m=date('m')+1;
$y=date('Y');

$d=15;
echo date( 't-m-Y', strtotime( "{$d}.{$m}.{$y}" ) );
# > outputs: 31-12-2015

$d=30;
echo date( 't-m-Y', strtotime( "{$d}.{$m}.{$y}" ) );
# > outputs: 31-12-2015
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$tstamp =  strtotime('+1 month');  //add a month
$m=date('m',$tstamp);   //month value
$y=date('Y');  //this year
$date15 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("$y-$m-"."15"));  //15 th of next month
$date31 = date("Y-m-t", strtotime("$y-$m-"."15")); //last date of next month
```

This will give you last date of next month.